Texture Stretching Vertically on a Cylindrical Mesh with Fabric.js Canvas in Three.js
I'm working on a 3D mug model (a cylindrical mesh) in Three.js and trying to apply a dynamic texture created using a Fabric.js canvas. However, the texture is being stretched vertically on the mesh, even though I have unwrapped the UVs and calculated the aspect ratio based on the 3D geometry. Note: I'm relatively new to Three.js, Fabric.js, and UV mapping, so I may be missing some key concepts or best practices. Any explanation or guidance on how to approach this would be helpful!
What I’m Trying to Achieve:

Apply a Fabric.js canvas as a texture on a cylindrical 3D mesh (mug).
Ensure the texture fits correctly around the cylindrical surface without any vertical stretching.
Dynamically update the texture using Fabric.js (adding shapes, text, etc.).

What I’ve Done So Far:

I’ve calculated the aspect ratio of the canvas using the 3D mesh’s bounding box:


Used the bounding box dimensions to calculate the width and height of the cylinder.
Calculated the arc length of the cylinder using the angle between the top-left and top-right corners of the bounding box.
Used the arc length and height of the mesh to adjust the aspect ratio of the Fabric.js canvas.


I’ve applied the texture using meshStandardMaterial in Three.js and updated the canvas dimensions accordingly.

The Problem:
Despite these adjustments, the texture is stretched vertically on the 3D model. Also, when I try to increase the canvas width, the height becomes too small, which results in even more stretching.
// Fabric.js canvas component
useEffect(() => {
    const geometry = nodes.Cylinder001_1_4.geometry;

    // Compute bounding box
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  
    const boundingBox = geometry.boundingBox;
    const width = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x;
    const height = boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y;
    const cylinderRadius = width / 2;

    // Angle and arc length calculation
    const topLeftCorner = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.min.x, boundingBox.max.y, boundingBox.min.z);
    const topRightCorner = new THREE.Vector3(boundingBox.max.x, boundingBox.max.y, boundingBox.min.z);
    const angle = topLeftCorner.angleTo(topRightCorner); // radians
    const arcLength = angle * cylinderRadius;

    // Aspect ratio calculation
    const labelAspectRatio = arcLength / height;
    console.log('Adjusted Aspect Ratio:', labelAspectRatio);

    // Setting canvas dimensions based on aspect ratio
    const canvasWidth = 700;
    const canvasHeight = canvasWidth / labelAspectRatio;
    State.canvasWidth = canvasWidth;
    State.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;

}, []);

// Applying texture in Three.js
<mesh geometry={nodes.Cylinder001_1_4.geometry}>
    <meshStandardMaterial
        map={texture} // Fabric.js canvas texture
        toneMapped={false}
        transparent
        polygonOffset
        polygonOffsetFactor={-1}
    />
</mesh>

What I’ve Tried:

Verified UV Mapping: I unwrapped the cylinder mesh in Blender, ensuring that the UV map was laid out properly. The UV map appears to cover the entire texture correctly in Blender’s UV Editor.
Adjusting Aspect Ratio: Calculated the aspect ratio of the cylinder’s geometry based on its arc length and height, and resized the Fabric.js canvas accordingly.
Experimenting with Different Canvas Sizes: Tried using different widths and heights, but the texture continues to stretch vertically.

Results:

The canvas height is much smaller compared to the width.
The texture on the 3D mesh appears stretched vertically, despite the UV mapping looking correct in Blender.

My Questions:

Why is the texture being stretched vertically on the cylindrical mesh even though I calculated the aspect ratio?
Is there a specific way to handle UV maps in Three.js when applying dynamic textures like this?
Is there a better way to ensure the texture fits properly around the cylindrical surface without distortion?

here is the repo don't mind the name of the repo
here is an image in blender  the mug has a cylindrical mesh that has a cut at the handle this is where the texture should be placed 
here is an image of the demo 3dmug
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
